# No response from api in development enviroment, but works in production environment

Tags: trustpilot

Getting no response from the api when I try and debug using my development environment to connect to the api.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us more about it (code, details, etc..)?

If you call your own API have you checked your CORS reponse status in development mode?

If it's the case, it's a common pseudo-issue, you can solve it by installing a browser addon.